# Can LIB paths be set in rc.local? Does it execute its commands after we login?

Tags: bashrc, runlevel

1. Does rc.local execute its commands after we login?
2. Since rc.local executes its commands after the multi user runlevel completes, does it also mean that we can/should set LIB paths in it instead of setting them in .bashrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script `/etc/rc.local` is invoked at the end of normal system startup. It is executed as `root` and has no relationship whatsoever with a user logging in. Any environment variable assignments in `/etc/rc.local` are available only to the processes started by `/etc/rc.local`; they are not available to processes started in a user's login session.

`/etc/rc.local` has no direct effect on a user's login session. It is normally used to mount some disks, start some services and other such tasks. It cannot be used to set up a user's environment.

First, let's look into `/etc/rc.local` itself:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

`rc.local` is an old feature of Unix-like system, older even than the System V initialization system (the one which used the directories `/etc/rc[0-6S].d`). Recent Ubuntu systems used [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) to control initialization; `/etc/rc.local` is invoked by the `systemd` unit `rc-local.service`:

```
$ sudo systemctl status rc-local
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
       └─debian.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-04-28 17:44:18 EEST; 2 days ago

Apr 28 17:44:18 factissa systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Apr 28 17:44:18 factissa systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

The unit is automatically generated at boot if the file `/etc/rc.local` exists, and is set by default to be invoked after achieving `network.target`; on Debian and derivatives such as Ubuntu, a drop-in configuration file modifies this so that the unit is run after `network-online.target`.

This is not exactly the same as the traditional place of `/etc/rc.local` at the end of a multi-user runlevel initialization, but it's similar enough so that in most cases no adjustments need to be done. (Look into those files, they are text and quite understandable; to make modifications please read the `systemd` documentation first.)